# Build a standalone JMS client using JAVA

Tags: client, jms, jms-topic

I am new to JMS and I need to build a generic JMS client to create a connection send and receive message by using queues and topics. I have seen many example using activeMQ connection factory, but I need a generic client which can use any connection factory and create a connection. Any leads or sample codes will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just done that recently. Steps I've taken

1. Read Java JMS tutorials to understand what is JMS.
2. You can code in Java or use a framework for example - Spring JMS
3. Read about MQ provider docs. for example activeMQ or IBM MQ.

Comment: Can you please share your code for sample? In need to build a client which will be more generic and not dependent for ActiveMQ or IBM MQ.